# nltk only processing last string in txt file

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, stop-words

I have a .txt file with four strings, all split by a line break.

When I tokenize the file, it processes every line of data, which is perfect.

However, when I attempt to remove stop words from the file, it only removes the stop words from the last string.

I want to process all content within the file, not just the last sentence.

My code:

```
 with open ('example.txt') as fin:
    for tkn in fin:
        print(word_tokenize(tkn))


#STOP WORDS
stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))

words = word_tokenize(tkn)

stpWordsRemoved = []

for stp in words:
    if stp not in stop_words:
        stpWordsRemoved.append(stp)

print("STOP WORDS REMOVED: " , stpWordsRemoved)
```

Output:

```
['this', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'how', 'stop', 'words', 'are', 'utilized', 'in', 'natural', 'language', 'processing', '.']
[]
['drive', 'driver', 'driving', 'driven']
[]
['smile', 'smiling', 'smiled']
[]
['there', 'are', 'multiple', 'words', 'here', 'that', 'you', 'should', 'be', 'able', 'to', 'use', 'for', 'lemmas/synonyms', '.']
STOP WORDS REMOVED:  ['multiple', 'words', 'able', 'use', 'lemmas/synonyms', '.']
```

As you can see above, it only processes the last line.

edit: 
The content of my txt file:

```
this is an example of how stop words are utilized in natural language processing.
A driver goes on a drive while being driven mad. He is sick of driving.  

smile smiling smiled 

there are multiple words here that you should be able to use for lemmas/synonyms.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider merging your remove stopwords function in your readline loop as the following:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
with open("d:/example.txt") as the_file:
    for each_line in the_file:
        print(nltk.word_tokenize(each_line))
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(each_line)
        stp_words_removed = []
        for word in words:
            if word not in stop_words:
                stp_words_removed.append(word)
        print("STOP WORDS REMOVED: ", stp_words_removed)
```

From your description it looks like you've only fed the last line to the stopword remover. What I don't understand is if that's the case you shouldn't be getting all these empty lists.

Comment: This works. I will be using more nltk techniques such as lemmatizing, speech tagging etc. Will I have to include these in this loop in order for this to read the whole content? I imagine it would get quite messy.

Also, the I believe the empty list outputs I'm getting is just the linebreaks.

Comment: @Yunter You may also store it in some other variable, such as appending your list of words (tokens) into another list to use in the future. By the way, check my answer if you like it and I would love to discuss with you further on this topic.

Comment: Checked, thanks. I would for sure prefer to store it in a variable as it may be cleaner that way. I have tried to do that, but it is still only storing the last string.

Comment: @Yunter this is what I would do: `article = [] for each_line in the_file:
        print(nltk.word_tokenize(each_line))
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(each_line)
        article.append(words)`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. I'm having issue now lemmatizing this list as it is printing the strings in the file multiple times (each string is printed a different number of times). If I cannot debug this I'll likely ask another question as it is different to this thread. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the result of word_tokenize to a list and then process the list. In your example you are only taking the last line of the file after you iterate over it.

**Try:**

```
words = []
with open ('example.txt') as fin:
   for tkn in fin:
       if tkn:
           words.append(word_tokenize(tkn))

#STOP WORDS
stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))

stpWordsRemoved = []

for stp in words:
    if stp not in stop_words:
        stpWordsRemoved.append(stp)

print("STOP WORDS REMOVED: " , stpWordsRemoved)
```

Comment: This causes the following error:

if stp not in stop_words:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Sorry I think I added an extra set of bracket around the word_tokenize method. Updated solution can you try again?

Comment: Can you post your text content also?  So that I can test the snippet

Comment: I have posted it now. Thanks